# Jersey Service with Object as parameter

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I´ve some Jersey services as follows

```
      @GET
      @Path("/GetUsers")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
      public List<Campania> findUsers(@QueryParam("userName") String User) {
        List<User> users= userBL.getUsers();
        return users;
      }
```

My problem is that this method should receive 10 parameters, so I would prefer to have only one parameter: GetUsersFilter which contains the 10 parameters.

The only way I know for doint that, is changing from @GET to @POST, but, this services should be a GET. There is another way?

Comment: So, all your parameters are passed as query params (e.g. `...?param1=value1&param2=value2&...&param10=value10`)?

Comment: @isnot2bad i´m using javax.ws.rs.client.Client to consume the services

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [@BeanParam](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/BeanParam.html) annotation to bundle multiple query parameters (and other stuff) into a single java object:

```
// parameter object that bundles all parameters
public class UserQueryParams {
    @QueryParam("userName")
    private String user;

    @QueryParam("param2")
    private String param2;

    ...
    // getters etc.
}
```

Then in your JAX-RS resource method, use it as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("/GetUsers")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
public List<User> findUsers(@BeanParam UserQueryParams userQuery) {
    List<User> users = userBL.getUsers(userQuery);
    return users;
}
```

Comment: I see, thats great, but how can avoid doing a lot of .queryParam in the client:

 users = client.target(URLS)
 .path("findUsers")
         .queryParam("userName", "test")
         .queryParam("param2", "")
         .etc

Cant i do something like .beanParam("", userQueryParams)

Comment: I don't think, this is possible. But even if it were, calling all setters on the bean first is the same amount of code to write...

Comment: mmm... no, me UserQueryParmas beans is loaded using struts2 automatically, so, y never have to call the setters :). Also, i have an intermediate services "dummy", just call another with the same parameters, so i have to do it both.